# Iterate through Map Items when using a Tuple Key

Tags: ink

When using Ink to store data in a Mapping with a tuple Key, how do you iterate through all the elements in a tuple?

thanks,

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: yes. as in the erc721 example. 
operator_approvals: Mapping<(AccountId, AccountId), ()>

Comment: so for each account there are many operators accounts. how to iterate through the operators for each main account.

Answer (score 1):

Looping through tuples is not ideal (to put it lightly) since they are not heterogeneous.

You could tackle this in two ways:

- As you commented yourself: creating another mapping where the associated AccountId's (operator accounts) are mapped to an AccountId.
- Mapping with Vec, an example of such a nested structure: https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/f03f2a6d63d85caa0cc8a361e5b78948268d2645/examples/mother/lib.rs#L40

Answer (score 0):

As per this [issue](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11410), right now it can't possible to iterate over storage.

Comment: so would you need to store another mapping of tuples that maps to an array of Ids for each element in the tuple?